# Send notifications when the app is not used?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, push-notification

A client of mine had the question of whether it is possible to send a push notification in the employee app if they have not entered their hours by a certain time.

Is it possible to create a service for Android and iOS apps that checks every hour if the hours of the day have been entered in the database, and if not then send a push notification?

I don't know where to start, and if it is possible. But if other apps can do it, it should be possible with this app as well.

Comment: "_when app is not running delphi_" can be misunderstood - consider punctuation and proper casing.

Comment: It is certainly possible to make a background service that is always running, monitoring the database and sending notifications. I would have the main app communicate with the service to add hours when needed, so all of the database logic is kept isolated.

Comment: You could design your app so that it creates specific notification messages that should fire at specific time just before your app closes. And then on your app start you clear those still unfired notifications from the notification manager so that they won't show while your app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SilverWarior Suggests I have created two pieces of code one makes the notifications when the app goes to the background then when the app goes to the foreground I clear `Tnotificationcenter`. I've used the `appevent` function to trigger the `enterdbackground` and `willbecomeforground`.

The Appevent code looks like this:

```
function TForm1.AppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
begin
 case AAppEvent of
     TApplicationEvent.EnteredBackground:
      begin


         Gethourregistration(FEmployeeNr,NOW);
          if dm.MthourregistrationControl.RecordCount<1 then
            begin
           var Notification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
            try
            Notification.Name := 'message1';
            Notification.AlertBody := 'You have not yet entered todays hours!';
                Notification.FireDate :=Date+encodetime(19,0,0,0);

            { Send notification in Notification Center }
            NotificationCenter1.ScheduleNotification(Notification);


              Notification.Name := 'message2';
            Notification.AlertBody := 'You have not yet entered todays hours!';
                Notification.FireDate :=Date+encodetime(21,0,0,0);

            { Send notification in Notification Center }
            NotificationCenter1.ScheduleNotification(Notification);   

            finally
              Notification.Free;
            end;


          end;

      end;
      TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeForeground:
        Notificationcenter1.CancelAll;

    end;
end;
```

I use the OnCreate event for asking permission for sending notifications and trigger the AppEvent.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
AppEventSvc: IFMXApplicationEventService;

begin
  if NotificationCenter1.AuthorizationStatus <> TAuthorizationStatus.Authorized then
  begin
    FPendingAction := Action;
    NotificationCenter1.RequestPermission;
  end;
    if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService, IInterface(AppEventSvc)) then
    begin
        AppEventSvc.SetApplicationEventHandler(AppEvent);
    end;
end;
```

I have tested this code and for me, this works perfectly.